# Java Updating: On LInux Mint the openjdk package doesn't update to the latest stable version

Tags: java, linux

On Linux Mint I have installed `openjdk` from the terminal using `$ sudo apt install openjdk-9-jdk`.  However, when I enter `java -version` it returns

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

which seems to be an out-of-date version.  When I run `$ sudo apt install openjdk-9-jdk` it alerts me that it is the latest version.  I don't find any information on how to ... I guess force a more current update, since presumably what I've done is supposed to obtain the most recent update.  However, the fact that this is not the most recent is the best guess I can find for why I'm unable to install Eclipse, so I really do need the most recent version.

Comment: Java 9 is eol. Java 10 or Java 8 are what Oracle currently supports (unless you have an extended support agreement).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it--I reverted to Java 8 and this totally fixed all my problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 9 is [eol](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html), from the link, Java 9 was a non-LTS (long term support) and Personal User End of Public Updates was in March of 2018. As of today, supported versions are Java 8 and Java 10 (released in March 2018). Further note

> Oracle will continue to provide Public Updates and auto updates of Java SE 8, until at least the end of December 2020 for Personal Users, and January 2019 for Commercial Users.